# Get ScopeContext properties in AsyncTaskTarget

Tags: c#, nlog, microsoft.extensions.logging

I am implementing a custom **NLog** `AsyncTaskTarget`, and I need to retrieve values that I have added using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.BeginScope`:

```
using (var scope = logger.BeginScope(new []
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("userId", this.UserId)
}))
{
    logger.Log(..);
}
```

Rendering this in a layout using `${mdlc:userId}` works fine, but I would like to get them directly from `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext` or `ScopeContext`.

This is what I've tried:

```
protected override async Task WriteAsyncTask(LogEventInfo logEvent, CancellationToken token)
{
    // returns null
    ScopeContext.TryGetProperty("userId", out var userId);
    userId = MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.GetObject("userId");

    // this works fine
    var message = this.Layout.Render(logEvent);
}
```

How do I get the `userId` value from the scope?

NLog Version: 5.0.1 (newest)

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3301) is related to this problem, but I found no real solution there.

Comment: What's the value of `this.Layout`? What are the NLog versions? And what is the result of `ScopeContext.GetAllNestedStates()`?

Comment: @Julian `this.Layout` is of type `TargetWithContextLayout`. You can use any layout you want, point is, when you use `${mdlc:userId}` in it, it will get properly rendered as the `userId` I added to the scope. NLog version is latest (`5.0.1`). `ScopeContext.GetAllNestedStates()` was empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Target-constructor enable the  option:

- [IncludeScopeProperties](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/P_NLog_Targets_TargetWithContext_IncludeScopeProperties.htm) = true;

And then you can use [GetScopeContextProperties()](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_Targets_TargetWithContext_GetScopeContextProperties.htm) method:

```cs
protected override async Task WriteAsyncTask(LogEventInfo logEvent, CancellationToken token)
{
    var contextProperties = GetScopeContextProperties(logEvent);
    contextProperties?.TryGetValue("userid", out var userId);
}
```

You can also get a combined dictionary of all properties, by using [GetAllProperties()](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_Targets_TargetWithContext_GetAllProperties.htm) and the do the lookup (Still need to enable [IncludeScopeProperties](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/P_NLog_Targets_TargetWithContext_IncludeScopeProperties.htm) )

Comment: This is a step forward, but strangely though, this seems to return not the original object, but a ToString() representation, at least for reference types.

Comment: NLog cannot guarantee the object-lifetime of scope-properties (example they could have been disposed after scope exit). You can override [SerializeScopeContextProperty](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_Targets_TargetWithContext_SerializeScopeContextProperty.htm) to exclude / include object-types that can be trusted as immutable (just like string-object).

Comment: I figured. My scope values are all immutable, so this will work perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`GetAllProperties`](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_Targets_TargetWithContext_GetAllProperties.htm) method to get dictionary of all configured properties for `logEvent`, and then retrieve specific property from the dictionary. Just enable [`IncludeScopeProperties`](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/P_NLog_Targets_TargetWithContext_IncludeScopeProperties.htm) of the target in [NLog configuration](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file).

Comment: @marsze, I used it in [my NLog target implementation](https://gitlab.com/koryukov/nlog-graylog). Rolf Kristensen is an NLog developer and he provided the same solution in the second part of his post.

Comment: Yes, `IncludeScopeProperties` was the crucial piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

Full solution:

```
using NLog;
using NLog.Targets;

class AsyncScopeTarget : AsyncTaskTarget
{
    public AsyncScopeTarget()
    {
        this.IncludeScopeProperties = true;
    }

    protected override bool SerializeScopeContextProperty(LogEventInfo logEvent, string name, object value, out object serializedValue)
    {
        // return the original (immutable) value
        serializedValue = value;
        return true;
    }

    protected override async Task WriteAsyncTask(LogEventInfo logEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var scopeValues = GetScopeContextProperties(logEvent);
        if (scopeValues is not null)
        {
            scopeValues.TryGetValue("name", out object? scopeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

*(Note: Also consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322716/2060966) post.)*