# AsyncTaskTarget cannot get scope properties (but TargetWithContext can)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog, microsoft.extensions.logging

I tried to implement the solution from this SO post: [Get ScopeContext properties in AsyncTaskTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72801038/get-scopecontext-properties-in-asynctasktarget).

However, the solution seems to (no longer?) work. Or, more accurately, it does work with `TargetWithContext`:

```
public class ExampleTarget : TargetWithContext
{
    public ExampleTarget()
    {
        this.IncludeScopeProperties = true;
    }

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        // works!
        var scopeValues = GetScopeContextProperties(logEvent);
    }
}
```

but does not with `AsyncTaskTarget` (even thought that inherits from `TargetWithContext`):

```
public class ExampleTarget : AsyncTaskTarget
{
    public ExampleTarget()
    {
        this.IncludeScopeProperties = true;
    }

    protected override async Task WriteAsyncTask(LogEventInfo logEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // returns NULL!
        var scopeValues = GetScopeContextProperties(logEvent);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

I am using `NLog.Web.AspNetCore 5.2.3` (which uses `NLog 5.1.3` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 7.0.0`).

Scope values are added similar to this:

```
using (_logger.BeginScope(new[]
{
    KeyValuePair.Create("example-key", "example-value")
}))
{
    _logger.LogInformation("test");
}
```

Comment: Could you create a pull-request for https://github.com/NLog/NLog with an unit-test, that reproduces the issues? Tried running existing unit-test `AsyncTaskTarget_TestLogging` and the `AsyncTaskTestTarget` correctly receives dictionary when calling `GetScopeContextProperties`. Alternative you can create an issue an attach an example-project that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this was caused because the custom target was still inside an **async wrapper** via the configuration file:

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" name="exampleTargetAsync" overflowAction="Block">
      <target xsi:type="ExampleTarget" name="exampleTarget" />
  </target>
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="exampleTargetAsync" />
</rules>
```

Removing the wrapper fixed the issue.

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="ExampleTarget" name="exampleTarget" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="exampleTarget" />
</rules>
```

The wrapper should not be necessary anymore anways, because the target is now already async. However, I was not expecting this to break it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to diagnose this issue. You have found a bug, and it will be fixed with the upcoming NLog v5.1.5. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/5229

Comment: NLog v5.1.5 has been released - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/5.1.5#release-body-tab